# Performing a search that is not security trimmed

Tags: 2013, search, security-trimming, runwithelevatedprivileges, keywordquery

I'm trying to documents of a certain content type that has a certain tagging (the documents are spread over several site collection). To get some performance I'm trying to do it with a `KeywordQuery`.

The problem I have is that the user executing the code might not have access to all documents, but the check must still be made on all documents. Therefore I have tried to run the query in an elevated mode:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite eSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(eSite);
        keywordQuery.QueryText = "Some search query";
        keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
        resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
    }
});
```

This code returns an error

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

on this row `KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(eSite);`

Then I tried opening up the `SPSite` with the user token of the system account, like this:

```
using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(siteCollection.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
     KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(scSite);
     keywordQuery.QueryText = "Some query"
     keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
     SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
     ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
     var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
     resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This throws no error, but returns results only for the logged in user (not the system account).

Is it possible to execute a `KeywordQuery` in elevation, or without security trimming, without using some hardcore impersonation?

Comment: Are you referring any managed properties in query text, and if they marked to be indexed and searchable?

Comment: @FalakMahmood, I do not see how that is relevant to the question? Yes I do, and yes the retreival works perfectly (the problem is only that the results is security trimmed still)

Comment: I misunderstood the question, thinking if query ever worked. I believe underlying error message is more do with permissions than anything else. Why don't you try `SPSite` constructor, which receives system account user token `SPUserToken` from new but existing site collection object `SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint1");` `SPUserToken systoken = site.SystemAccount.UserToken;`

Comment: Like I already do above? Or should I try retreiving the system account token from the actual web instead of the `SPUserToken.SystemAccount`?

Comment: Yes, get it from actual site instead

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Do you know why it would actually be different to get the token that way? To me they seem to refer to the same token?

Comment: That gives exactly the same results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think @LeopoldLerch is on to the correct approach.

Try doing the following

```
Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
SPUserToken systemAccountUserToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
HttpContext currentUserContext = HttpContext.Current;

if (SPContext.Current != null)
    HttpContext.Current = null;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(siteId, systemAccountUserToken))
    {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, elevatedSite.RootWeb.Url, string.Empty);
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(httpRequest, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
        SPControl.SetContextWeb(HttpContext.Current, elevatedSite.RootWeb);

        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(elevatedSite);
        keywordQuery.QueryText = "Some query"
        keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
        // And then try setting SiteContext as well. Might not be necessary, but try it.
        keywordQuery.SiteContext = new Uri(elevatedSite.Url);
        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
        resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
    }
});

HttpContext.Current = currentUserContext;
```

Comment: The part with checking if `SPContext.Current` is null the second time (when to set `HttpContext.Current` back does not work since `SPContext.Current` becomes `null` on setting `HttpContext.Current` to `null`. Do you recognize that?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Yes I do recognize that. Copy/pasted the code from a project where I had a situation where it might end up becoming null again before reaching that point. Removed it from here.

Comment: After changing the last row to `if(HttpContext.Current == null)` it seems to work better!

Comment: Dude! It seems to work (without the `keywordQuery.SiteContext`)! Not sure how your code differs from the original trials but something around nulling the context and getting the `systemAccountUserToken` seems to solve it!

Comment: @RobertLindgren Cool :) I'm glad it solved it.

Comment: Cannot give you the bounty for another 16 hours (=pleanty of time for me to double and triple test it ;))

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete the current httpcontext before elevating (but do not forget to remember it and set it back

like

```
var storedContext = HttpContext.Current;
HttpContext.Current = null;
<Do something>
HttpContext.Current = storedContext;
```

Because it seems to use still your curentUsers Credentials when calling the search service (which it still does in the background). This trick works also in similar cases;

Comment: I've seen this when working with metadata-service and user profile-service. I will give it a try as soon as I have a minute :)

Comment: I will do it in a `try catch finally` to make sure to not kill the `HttpContext.Current` though ;)

Comment: Sadly, still the same behavior of executing the query as current user!